# How to get the filter data result in core data swift 5, with completion handler

Tags: swift, sorting, core-data, filtering, executefetchrequest

I have created the fetch data method in with completion handler and pass the two parameter search text and fetchOfSet but I did not get the response. I have to also sort the record and filter the records as descending order.

```
func fetchAllExpenses(searchText:String, page_no:Int,completionHandler: @escaping (_ responseHandler:[Expense]) -> Void, errorHandler: @escaping (_ error: Error) -> Void) {

    var array = [Expense]()


    // filter the id descending order
    let idDescriptor: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "exp_id", ascending: false)

    // set the fetch limt data
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 5

    // sort the data by descending order
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [idDescriptor]

    // need to update every time because can not predicate how many rows before fetched
    fetchRequest.fetchOffset = page_no

    do{
        if let fetchResult = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [Expense]{

            for i in 0..<fetchResult.count {
                let expenses: Expense? = fetchResult[i]
                array.append(expenses!)
                completionHandler(array)
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {


            }
        }else{
            print("Not Found More Data")
        }
    } catch let error {
        errorHandler("Error whilve retrieving data..\(error.localizedDescription)" as! Error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all a Core Data fetch is synchronous. There's no need for a completion handler.

Basically the fetch request is missing. And rather than returning an error or an optional hand over the error to the caller. If no records are found the array is empty. And the parameter `searchText` is not used at all.

```
func fetchAllExpenses(pageNo: Int) throws -> [Expense] {

    let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<Expense> = Expense.fetchRequest()

    // filter the id descending order
    let idDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "exp_id", ascending: false)

    // set the fetch limt data
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 5

    // sort the data by descending order
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [idDescriptor]

    // need to update every time because can not predicate how many rows before fetched
    fetchRequest.fetchOffset = pageNo

    return try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
}
```